# Datagrid view double click using jquery with asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've got a gridView called gvLineItems in an asp.net page..
I want to throw in some jquery to allow for a double click on the row of the gridview and let it redirect to another page:

```
<script src="include/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var selected = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#divGridView table tbody tr").find("tr").dblclick(function(){
      window.location = "<%#ResolveUrl("~/Default2.aspx")%>?record=" + $(this).find("td:first").text();
   });
});

</script>
```

Does anyone see anything strange here?

Here is the real ugly asp.net ajax with the div etc...

```
<div id="divGridView" style="width:100%">
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="myPanel" runat="server" >
                                          <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:GridView GridLines="Horizontal" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="Small" DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#F0F8FF" BackColor="#E8E8E8" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#377CB1" ID="gvLineItems" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" >
                                            <Columns>

                                                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False">
                                                     <ItemTemplate>
                                                         <asp:Label ID="lblExpenseReportLineItemID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                     </ItemTemplate>
                                                  </asp:TemplateField>

                                                  <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="HeaderLevelCheckBox" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="SelectAllRows" runat="server" />
                                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelector" runat="server" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this)" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1%" />
                                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1%" />
                                                  </asp:TemplateField>   

                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ibAddLineItem" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/InsertRow.gif"   CommandName="Insert" ToolTip="Insert line item" />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                     <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>

                                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDelete" runat="server" CommandName="DeleteRow" ImageUrl="images/d.gif"
                                                            ToolTip="Delete Line Item?" />

                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Date" SortExpression="LineItemDate">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender TargetControlID="txtLineItemDate" ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server">
                                                            </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
                                                            <asp:TextBox  Width="60px" onchange='return isLessThanEndDate(this);' ID="txtLineItemDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LineItemDate") %>'>
                                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                                                        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="12%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>             

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comm.CU" SortExpression="Comm">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style=" border-style:solid; border-width:thin; border-color:#DDD;">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                <td ><asp:TextBox Enabled="False" ToolTip="Click Search...To find a commission" Width="40px" ID="txtComm" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CommissionID") %>' /></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr><td><asp:TextBox Enabled="False" ToolTip="Click Search...To find a cost unit" Width="40px" ID="txtWBS" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.WBSID") %>' /></td></tr>
                                                                <tr><td align="center"><a href='FindCommCost.aspx?ExpenseReportID=<%#Eval("ERID")%>&ExpenseReportLineItemID=<%#Eval("ID")%>'  style="color:Navy">Search...</a></td></tr>
                                                            </table>



                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Reason">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExpenseTypes" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlExpenseTypes_SelectedIndexChanged"  DataSource='<%# GetExpenseTypes() %>' SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ExpenseReasonID") %>' DataTextField="ExpenseReasonID" DataValueField="ExpenseReasonID" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>  

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Receipt" SortExpression="Date">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbReceipt" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.HasReceipt") %>' />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>             

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox Width="40px" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="ChangedAmount" ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AmountSpent") %>' />
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Currency" SortExpression="Currency">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrency" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCurrency_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSource='<%# GetCurrency() %>' SelectedValue='<%# Bind("CountryID") %>' DataTextField="CountryID" DataValueField="CountryID"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>  

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate" SortExpression="Rate">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox Width="33px" AutoPostBack="true" ID="txtRate" OnTextChanged="ChangedAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Rate") %>' /> 
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="USD" SortExpression="USD">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblUSD" runat="server"  Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AmountBackInUSD") %>' /> 
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="1%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Desc." SortExpression="Desc.">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:TextBox Width="100px" Font-Names="Arial" ToolTip="If the expense type is Entertainment this field is required!" ID="txtExpenseReasonDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ExpenseReasonDescription") %>' /> 
                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="1%" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>


                                                     <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Link" SortExpression="Link" DataNavigateUrlFields="AttachmentLink" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}"
                                                DataTextField="AttachmentLink" DataTextFormatString="Link" Target="_blank" >
                                                         <ControlStyle ForeColor="Navy" />
                                                         <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
                                                     </asp:HyperLinkField>

                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload File?" SortExpression="ID" >
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:FileUpload Width="90px" Font-Size="xx-small"  ID="fuAttachment" runat="server" />
                                                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" font-size="xx-small" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadTheFile" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" />
                                                        <ItemStyle Width="50%" />
                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#377CB1" />
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="AliceBlue" />
                                            <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterStyle" />
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                        <div style="width:100%">
                                            <br />
                                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="udProgress" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100" Visible="True" DynamicLayout="True"><ProgressTemplate><img border="0" src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading" /></ProgressTemplate></asp:UpdateProgress>
                                            <br />
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="width:100%; text-align:right;">
                                        <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tr>
                                        <td class="tableFields" style="height: 68px">
                                            &nbsp;</td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Panel ID="pGridControls" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="False">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Click Update to <u>save</u> any changes" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#377CB1"></asp:Label>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibSaveGrid" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/smallSave.gif" ToolTip="Save / refresh changes?" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="ibSaveGrid_Click" /><asp:ImageButton ID="ibDeleteGrid" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/smallDelete.gif" ToolTip="Delete checked rows?" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="ibDeleteGrid_Click" /></asp:Panel>
                                            <hr /> <h3>
                                                <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" Width="50%" HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor= "#F0FFF0" CssClass="PadIt">
                                                    <ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender ID="RoundedCornersExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="Panel5" Radius="6" Corners="All" BorderColor="#377CB1" Color="#F0FFF0">
                                                    </ajaxToolkit:RoundedCornersExtender>
                                                Employee Due (USD):<asp:Label ID="lblMessage3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                </asp:Panel>
                                                </h3> </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ibOk" />
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbSort" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="CheckBoxIDsArray" runat="server"></asp:Literal></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                            </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
```

**Here's my edit:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selected = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#divGridView table tbody tr").dblclick(function(){
      window.location = "<%#ResolveUrl("~/Default2.aspx")%>?ID=" + $(this).find("td:first").text();
   });
});

</script>
```

I've now almost got it working...I can see the correct ID number, got to work on why the redirect isnt working.

Comment: Your two lines do two different things. Which one do you want?

Comment: Just looking for a redirect location.

Comment: You arent POSTing anything, technically. You are just redirecting the browser to a new URL. Other then that, it looks fine. It would be hard to tell without more code. Have you already tested this and experiencing problems?

Comment: @Jeff - bad wording I meant redirect - sorry I'm rushing to get this old app fixed.  Its a classic asp.net 2.0 app :-p.  I edited the content.

Comment: @JonH post the rendered mark up from browser (view-source from browser and get the html for the div), please.

Comment: Have you considered calling doPostBack and running the redirect on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var selected = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#divGridView table tbody tr").dblclick(function(){
      //window.location = "<%#ResolveUrl("~/Search.aspx")%>?ID=" + $(this).find("td:first").text();
      window.location = "myURL/Search.aspx?ID=" + $(this).find("td:first").text();
   });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the gridview in a `<div id="divGridView" />` and try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#divGridView table tbody tr").dblclick(function(){
    var id= $(this).find("td:first").text();
      window.location = "<%#ResolveUrl("~/Default2.aspx")%>?record=" + id;
   });
});
```

Comment: @StackOverflowException - no errors like mine, but when I double click the grid view row it doesnt do anything.

Comment: @JonH can you post the rendered html for the grid, at least up to couple rows ?

Comment: if you are using a browser which has JS debugging, do this: $("#divGridView table tbody tr").length, and what value does it give you?

Comment: @JonH For the first TemplateField, which should be your `td:first`, can you do `style="display: none"` instead of `Visible="False"`

Comment: @StackOverflowException - I've used that as well, that still does not solve the initial issue.  See my response to @jamietre

Comment: Same thing I said :) but does css `display:none` actually work for table cells? Intuitively i sense problems.

Comment: @JonH instead of `window.location = "<%#ResolveUrl("~/Default2.aspx")%>?record=" + id;` , if you put `alert(id);` , does that work?

Answer (score 1):

The tag you're looking for to get your ID, `$(this).find("td:first").text()` has `Visible=false` which will cause it to not be rendered, so jQuery won't find it.
Easiest solution is probably to put the ID in a markup (like a `span`) that's just rendered invisible client-side using `display:none` in the first display column

Comment: @jamietre - I also thought this and changed the visibility to true but still the same issue

Comment: Could also be a problem of what you're trying to bind to. It looks like you're trying to bind the double click to a 'tr' tag - a row is not a clickable entity. Pull this up in Chrome and use the javascript debugger to set a break point and test out your jQuery to see what's getting returned. FYI - i don't know if this is universal or just me, but $ never works when using Chrome's script debugger, you have to type `jQuery` longhand to play in the immediate window.

Comment: Actually I take that back, about a row not being clickable, whaddya know, here's a nice simple example: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquey-make-entire-table-row-clickable/ ... I think in your situation the problem is the last `find` in the selector. That looks for a `tr` in the child elements - I think you just want to lose that last find. Also you don't need to identify each part of the heirarchy in the selector, `("#divGridView tr")` will do what you need.

Comment: @jarnietre - sorry I just saw you mentioned that :).

Comment: @jarnietre - almost got it, Im able to see the ID number however it is not redirecting to Default2.aspx, it keeps staying on default.aspx.